# Checking if two strings are equal

Tags: c#, string

I want to check if a string from the first line of a file, is equal with an another string.
The awkward part is that, the strings are the same, but my program doesn't return a true value.
The string is `teach` and the first line of the file is `teach` too.

```
string date = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(folder + "/NPC/" + score_npc + "/" + score_npc + ".txt" );
        if (condition)
        {
            string[] parametrii = date.Split('\n');
            if (parametrii[0].Equals("teach"))
               //instructions
```

I tried all the compare methods, i made my own function too. And my function said me that the `(parametrii[0])[0] == b`

Here is how the file looks like:

```
teach
poza1
poza2
end
```

Comment: Use System.IO.File.ReadAllLines

Comment: Have you checked the text encoding of the source document?

Comment: Debug it, line by line. And see the strings contents in debug-watcher, char by char.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Use the debugger, and break at parametrii[0].Equals("teach").

Comment: If your trying to find an exact match, `String.Contains` will return a boolean if it exist or not within your `String`.  *Case will matter.*

Comment: You can use `File.ReadLines(path).First().Trim().Equals("teach", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnorecase)`

Comment: Even if it turns out not to be the problem in this case, attempting to decode a file into a string without specifying an encoding is always a bug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's propably because new line character is not \n in the file. It may be \r\n instead.

Try [File.ReadAllLines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1(v=vs.110).aspx) instead:

```
string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(folder + "/NPC/" + score_npc + "/" + score_npc + ".txt" );
if (condition)
{
    if (lines[0].Equals("teach"))
         // instructions
}
```

**Edit**

As Grant Winney suggests, if you only need to manipulate first line (or not all of the) file, you may use [File.ReadLines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
string firstLine = File.ReadLines(path).First();
```

instead.

Comment: @GrantWinney, actually i need the whole content of the file, but i want to compare only the first line, you know ?

Answer (score 1):

Have u tried to change

```
string[] parametrii = date.Split('\n');
```

into

```
string[] parametrii = date.Split(Environment.NewLine);?
```

I suspect it's because your strings contain '\r' character